# Window 'XXX- Internet Explorer' is blocking the control while trying to assign value in a popup

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, coded-ui-tests

I have an windows application in which, on click of a hyperlink, a popup will get displayed. This popup has a table and each cell in that table has an edit box. I have to assign values to that edit boxes. But when I try to assign value, Coded UI control hits the address bar and throws exception "Window 'XXX- Internet Explorer' is blocking the control . Please move the window 'XXX- Internet Explorer' or make the control visible and retry the action. 
Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
AccessibleName:  'Address and search using Google'
ClassName:  'Edit'
ControlType:  'Window'"

Comment: try setting focus on the popup window before editing it: controlName.SetFocus();

Comment: I want to reset the values in the controls(not in UI) once after assigning values in 1st row. How to do that? Because, after assigning values in 1st row, when it comes to 2nd row, the cell count shows 7 (adds both 1st and 2nd row's cell count) but it is supposed to show 4.

Comment: i'm not sure what you need - please add some code example and screen captures if possible